# How to assign value to ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Here is controller code:

```
    $scope.FormData.Quantity = $scope.sum();
```

Here is HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="FormData.Quantity" ng-model="FormData.Quantity" />
```

Displaying blank textbox. How to assign?

Comment: Either $scope.sum() is a null or undefined or a blank string, or there is another problem, in all the code your're not posting. Pst a complete minimal example, in a plunkr for example.

Answer (score 0):

you have assign function to ng-model , which may not returning anythinmg , try this one...

```
 $scope.FormData = {};
 $scope.sum =  function(){
    return "whatever";
 };
 $scope.FormData.Quantity = $scope.sum();
```